# select nth node in xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using this XPATH query:

```
xpath.compile("/TEI.2/text/body/div/entry/sense/cit/quote[text()="malta"]")
```

I'd like to get the 2nd "quote" node containing "malta". How can I do that?

I have tried:

`xpath.compile("/TEI.2/text/body/div/entry/sense/cit/quote[text()="malta" and position()=2]")`

as well as

```
xpath.compile("/TEI.2/text/body/div/entry/sense/cit/quote[text()="malta"][2]")
```

These give me an empty result however I'm sure there is a second node.

Thanks!

Comment: The third one doesn't work, I've tried it out again just now. And about the xml, I can't put it over here.

Comment: Try use `normalize-space(text())`

Comment: just post your xml, you can remove sensitive information ;)

Comment: Post sample XML which reproduces your issue.

Comment: It's not clear from the question, perhaps you want `(…original xpath query…)[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I had to add brackets to the expression before the final [2]

I.e.

```
xpath.compile("(/TEI.2/text/body/div/entry/sense/cit/quote[text()="malta"])[2]")
```

Thanks still!

Comment: Krt_Malta, Brackets are only needed if the XPath `//` pseudo-operator is used -- which in your XPath expression isn't used. Therefore, either you are misleading the readers and you are actually having a different XPath expression, or the XPath engine you are using isn't a compliant XPAth implementation.